# Generate a TopoJSON

Tags: json, node.js, git, gdal

I want to generate a json file with this github.

https://github.com/interactivethings/swiss-maps

So i have installed Node and GDAL and try do what README says.

```
Welcome to Git (version 1.8.5.2-preview20131230)


Run 'git help git' to display the help index.
Run 'git help <command>' to display help for specific commands.

Marc P@PCDEMARC ~
$ cd swiss-maps

Marc P@PCDEMARC ~/swiss-maps (master)
$ make
sh.exe": make: command not found
```

What i'm doing wrong? I'm obviously a beginner, it's why the README isn't enough clear for me... ;D

Comment: What kind of system is this?

Comment: The instructions in the README you reference are for Mac OS X.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. Somebody has a clue how to do it under windows?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Make" command for Windows - possible options?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16755641/make-command-for-windows-possible-options)