# Can a CMD batch file or PowerShell script execute multiple g++ commands?

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd

I like using both Linux and Windows for my C and C++ coding and I prefer using the command line to compile my programs.  I can run make on Linux, which is fine.  But on Windows, now that I'm working with classes and have to compile multiple files, I find it a chore to type in several g++ commands to compile the class and main object files.

I was wondering if there's a way to get a CMD batch file or PowerShell script to just execute the commands one after the other?

Something like this:

```
g++ -c Area.cpp -o Area.o
g++ -c Convert.cpp -o Convert.o
g++ -c Calculate.cpp -o Calculate.o
g++ -c multi_menu_functions.cpp -o multi_menu_functions.o
g++ -c main.cpp -o main.o
g++ -Wall main.o Area.o Calculate.o Convert.o multi_menu_functions.o -o main
```

...Something dead simple and easy.

Comment: The commentary on the tag you used says "A batch file is a text file containing a series of commands that are executed by the command interpreter on MS-DOS, IBM OS/2, or Microsoft Windows systems." But more usual to use a formal make file.

Comment: look here for options for continuing to use "make": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16755641/make-command-for-windows-possible-options

Comment: `g++ Area.cpp Convert.cpp Calculate.cpp multi_menu_functions.cpp main.cpp -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic-errors -o main.exe`. Or just use `make`. There is a make distributed with g++, and there's Microsoft's `nmake`. Or use Microsoft's build system `msbuild`. Or Cmake. Or, just put all those commands you have in a batch file. I fail to see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just write the commands in a file with extension `.bat` and you can just start that file. You can turn off outputting the commands while execution of the batch file by starting the file with the line `@echo off`.

Or better yet: Just get `make` for windows and use that one.

Comment: I did put the commands in a .bat file, they won't run as is.  Are there specific DOS keywords to execute the g++ commands?  I know there are several make out there for windows, but I wanted to know if you can do it with a .bat or powershell script.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue of why the g++ commands wouldn't work as is:  somehow the laptop I was using didn't grant me the correct permissions.  At a guess I tried the full path name for g++.exe and it worked.  I reconfigured some things and now it works with the commands as listed.

On a side note; I did get gnumake and minGW make working as well.  Since these can run my Linux makefiles I'll use these as well.