# Error Building and installing local chainlink node, when running make install - windows

Tags: chainlink

I am trying to create a local chainlink oracle node, for testing and learning purposes. Using windows 10.

I followed the steps listed on the https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink#install
to install a local chainlink node.

Already installed Go, nodeJS, nvm, yarn, postgres (all latest version as of 21/11/04. All ruuning from root).

Downloaded the Chainlink executing: git clone https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink && cd chainlink

changed the directory to C:\chainlink

and ran make install command to build and install the node.

Got the error:

'make' is not recognized as an intern or extern command, operable program or a batch file

What am I doing wrong?
(Apparently, make install is a command that works for mac command line, I am using windows instead)

Comment: Hi, can you try out the suggestions in this post and let me know if that helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16755641/make-command-for-windows-possible-options

Comment: Hi Zak, thanks for the comment. I have installed cygwin, but I am not sure how it´s going to help me. When i run cigwin, it opens a different terminal that seems to work in a kind of virtual envinroment. I can´t even find the directories I need inside cigwin.

Comment: No problem, I have left an answer. Cgywin isn't actually a virtual environment but attempts to create a Linux-like experience on windows. Many are using WSL instead now. 

The recommended process here would be to download docker and use that as described in the docs. Other than that, you would need to use the methods described in my answer below to get it to run.

Answer (score 0):

Working on Windows, the easiest method of running a node would be to use [docker](https://www.docker.com/) and download the docker image as described in the [Chainlink docs](https://docs.chain.link/docs/running-a-chainlink-node/).

Make is a UNIX based command and will require either using a virtual UNIX/Linux environment, using a tool like Cgywin or WSL [as discussed in this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32127524/how-to-install-and-use-make-in-windows)